# I can't access my routes from the store Pinia Vuejs3

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vuejs3, pinia

I can't access my routes from the store.
There may be a good explanation for this.
I use Vuejs3 and Pinia

My store :

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";


type navigationState = {
    selectedNavigationItem: INavigationItem | null,
    selectedNavigationPage: INavigationPage | null,
}

export const useNavigationStore = defineStore('navigationStore', {
    state: () => ({
        /**
         * when the user clicks on an element of the navbar we store the navigation item here
         */
        selectedNavigationItem: null,
        /**
         * when the user clicks on an element of the sidebar we store the navigation page here
         */
        selectedNavigationPage: null,
    } as navigationState),
    actions: {

        /**
         * Set Selected navigation page
         * @param navigationPage
         * @type INavigationPage
         */
        setSelectedNavigationPage(navigationPage: INavigationPage | null) {
            console.log(useRoute())
            this.selectedNavigationPage = navigationPage
        },
    },
})
```

when I do a console log like in the method setSelectedNavigationPage

I have an undefined

Answer (score 6):

### EDIT: Thanks for [sophiews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13750640/sophiews) for pointing this out.

Just found out that we have different way to defineStore: [Setup Stores](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores)

```js
// src/stores/user.js

import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import api from './api.js'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('User', () => { // use function
  const route = useRoute()
  const router = useRouter()
  
  const login = async () => {
    await api.POST('login', {username, password})
    router.replace({name: 'home'})
  }

  return { login } // IMPORTANT: need to return anything we need to expose
})
```

### Old answer

You can add router as [Pinia plugin](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html)

```js
// src/main.js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp, markRaw } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import Home from './views/HomePage.vue'
import Api from './api.js' // my axios wrapper

const app = createApp(App)

// I usually put this in a separate file src/router.js and export the router
const routes = [ 
  { path: '/', component: HomePage },
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})

const pinia = createPinia()
pinia.use(({ store }) => {
  store.router = markRaw(router)
  store.api = markRaw(Api)
})

app
  .use(pinia)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app')
```

Then `router` and `api` are available on `this`

```js
// src/stores/user.js

import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useUserStore = defineStore('User', {
  state: () => ({}),
  actions: {
    async login() {
      await this.api.POST('login', {username, password})
      this.router.replace({name: 'home'})
    }
  }
})
```

Note that you can't call `this.router` with arrow function.

```js
login: async () => {
  this.router.replace({name: 'home'}) // error
}
```

#### For typescript user, to correctly get type for `this.router` and `this.api`:

```
// src/global.d.ts
import { Router } from 'vue-router'
import Api from './api'

export { }

declare global {

}

declare module 'pinia' {
  export interface PiniaCustomProperties {
    router: Router,
    api: typeof Api
  }
}
```

I found this way on pinia github.
https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1092

But I still don't know how to add `this.route` to Pinia.

Future reader, please comment if you know how to do it.

Comment: From [sophiews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13750640/sophiews), how to add `this.route` to Pinia (attempted edit): https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/623#discussioncomment-1226120

Comment: I am trying to do this using the function syntax (`const route = useRoute()`) but it keeps yelling at me: `route is undefined` when I try to access anything on the route. Is there any other setup you did to make that work?

Comment: @RobinG same problem here

Comment: @RobinG post your code as a question, maybe I can help

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74795749/how-to-use-useroute-userouter-in-a-pinia-store-using-setup-store-syntax-in-v

Comment: This is raw but it seems to do the trick for simple usage. He uses the router beforeEach method to provide the route to the store. If you need to pull data from the path you'll probably have to do your own string magic. Doesn't seem to populate the params property when manually entering the path. More testing needed but seems useable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893238/access-current-route-inside-a-getter-in-pinia

Answer (score 4):

#### `useRoute` and `useRouter` must be used in Vue components and specifically `setup` method or inside `script setup`.

[useRouter Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#userouter)

[useRoute Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute)

---

If you want to access the `router` though, you can simply import it:

*router-file*

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [/* ... */]
})
```

then in your pinia store you can import and use the router from that file:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import router from './router'

export const myStore = defineStore('myStore', () => {
  // router.push
  // router.replace
})
```

Comment: This breaks hot module reloading with this error `Cannot access 'MyComponent' before initialization`.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the process of instantiating a store within a factory/function, this will allow you to expand the stores capabilities regarding your custom needs. Below you can see that we can instantiate a store referencing the urql client and the router object.
Have a look:

```js
    export class StoreManager {
  static _instances: any[] = [];
  public static spawnInstance(
    id: string,
    storeType?: EStoreType,
    clientHandle?: ClientHandle,
    routerHandle?: Router,
  ) {

    if (StoreManager._instances.find((i) => i.id === id)) {
      const store = StoreManager._instances.find((i) => i.id === id).instance;
      return store;
    } else {
      const store = StoreManager.initStore(
        id,
        storeType,
        clientHandle ?? null,
        routerHandle ?? null,
      );
      StoreManager._instances.push({
        id: id,
        instance: store,
        storeType: storeType,
      });
      return store;
    }
  }

  public static initStore(
    id: string,
    storeType: EStoreType,
    clientHandle: ClientHandle | null,
    routerHandle: Router | null,
  ) {
    const baseState = {
      _meta: {        
        storeType: storeType,
        isLoading: true,        
      },
      _client: clientHandle,
      _router: routerHandle,
    };

    const baseActions = {
      async query(query: any, variables: any[] = []) {
        // use urql client
        
      },
    };
    const baseGetters = {
      storeType: (state) => state._meta.storeType,
      getCurrentRoute: (state) => {
        if (!state._router) {
          throw new RouterNotSetException(
            `This store does not have a router set up`,
          );
        }
        return state._router.currentRoute.fullPath.replace('/', '');
      },
    };

    switch (storeType) {
      case EStoreType.DEFAULT:
        return defineStore({
          id: `${id}`,
          state: () => ({
            ...baseState,
          }),
          actions: {
            ...baseActions,
          },
          getters: {
            ...baseGetters,
          },
        });

      default:
        throw new StoreTypeNotFoundException(
          `Expected valid 'EStoreType', got ${storeType}`,
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Within your VueComponent a store instance would be spawned like this:

```js
const store = StoreManager.spawnInstance(
  uuidv4(),
  EStoreType.DEFAULT,
  useClientHandle(),
  useRouter(),
)();
```