# How to use `useRoute`/`useRouter` in a Pinia Store using Setup Store syntax in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, state-management, pinia

I've been trying to get my Pinia store up and running in Vue 3 and it all has been pretty effortless until I wanted to access some parameters in the url.

I have a store (simplified) like so:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useLocalStorage } from '@vueuse/core';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const uuid = ref(
    useLocalStorage('uuid', route.params.id)
  )

 return { uuid };
})
```

Unfortunately, the route remains undefined as if `useRoute()` is not triggered properly. I've seen that you can add plugins to add the router instance to the pinia store on initialisation, but there's no way I can find to access that `this` instance in a Setup Store.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I want something similar. I tried using computed properties which works on load but loses reactivity after navigation.

Comment: I ended up just importing the `router` from my `router/index`. That seems to work without issue.

Answer (score 5):

`route` is not defined when the pinia is initiated.

You need to wait a bit.

One way to do this is to call the function when the component is loaded.

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const id = ref('');

  const setId = () => {
    id.value = route.params.id as string; // don't need as string if you don't use TypeScript
  };

  return { id, setId };
});
```

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useUserStore } from '../stores/user';
const user = useUserStore();

user.setId(); // call the function from pinia, route.params works just fine
</script>
```

[Link Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-zbehnb?file=src/stores/user.ts)

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, yeah that could work, but it is kind of verbose and not very elegant imo. That means that every time you want to call the userstore you would have to instantiate the route too, which you then don't use. I foresee that other people will forget that and that it'll cause issues in the long run.

Comment: @RobinG Sorry I forgot to remove the `useRoute` here. I imported it in the demo link just to show it in the template `{{ route.params.id }}`. You don't need to call `useRoute()` if you don't use it in the template. The important part is to call user.setId() on the component that can be accessed when the URL has params.id. If all your routes have it, then just put it in the App.vue.