# Access current route inside a getter in Pinia?

Tags: vuejs3, getter, pinia

I would like to know what is the current route so that I can compute the size of the sidebar.

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useSidebarStore = defineStore('sidebar', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      full: true // can be toggled by clicking on the sidebar toggle button
    }
  },
  getters: {
    // TODO secondarySidebar is open if current route is settings
    // secondarySidebarOpen: (state) =>
    // TODO create a getter that returns the current route
    currentRoute (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
      return 
    }
  },
  actions: {
  }
})

export default useSidebarStore
```

Can you please help?

Comment: `const route = useRoute()` will give you all the informations about the current route

Comment: @jeremycastelli thanks for commenting. Can you please give more details, how I access it from inside a getter?

Comment: I'm afraid I misread your question, sorry. I'm using pinia's setup stores and totally forgot this is not the default way of using pinia .  https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores 
I don't know if it's possible inside getters

Comment: @jeremycastelli Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to use this syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution I found is to store the current route to the state of the store by using beforeEach method of the router.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import routes from '@/router/routes.js'
import { useSidebarStore } from '@/stores/sidebar.js'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach(async (to) => {
  const sidebarStore = useSidebarStore()
  sidebarStore.currentRoutePath = to.path
  return true
})
export default router
```